# d3js Force Layout Not Working As Expected

Tags: javascript, d3.js, force-layout

I've been working on a D3JS force layout graph, that isn't quite working as expected.

I've uploaded my code to JSFiddle, and can be seen here:

http://jsfiddle.net/jonaths/e9L3aq4k/

I think the important part of it is the following, that deals with updating the threshold of the nodes / links:

```
function threshold(thresh) {

    graph.links.splice(0, graph.links.length);

    for (var i = 0; i < graphRec.links.length; i++) {
        if (graphRec.links[i].value > thresh) {
            graph.links.push(graphRec.links[i]);
        }
    }

    graph.nodes.splice(0, graph.nodes.length);
    for (var j = 0; j < graphRec.nodes.length; j++) {
        if (graphRec.nodes[j].value > thresh) {
            graph.nodes.push(graphRec.nodes[j]);
        }
    }

    restart();
}


//Restart the visualisation after any node and link changes

function restart() {
    node = node.data(graph.nodes);
    link = link.data(graph.links);
    link.exit().remove();
    node.exit().remove();
    node.enter().insert("circle", ".node").attr("class", "node").attr("r", function (d) {
        return d.value / 5
    }).style("fill", "steelblue").call(force.drag);
    link.enter().insert("line", ".node").attr("class", "link").call(force.drag);
    force.start();
}
```

The idea is that as the threshold is increased, nodes and links that don't meet that threshold are removed.  When the threshold is subsequently updated, additional links / nodes should be added / removed accordingly.

I used the [code here](http://www.coppelia.io/2014/07/an-a-to-z-of-extra-features-for-the-d3-force-layout/) as the basis for what I'm trying to do, but had to amend it to get the nodes to disappear, so there may well be an issue with my code.

Now what I'm finding, is that if you increase the threshold slowly, then it works perfectly.  However, if you just click the threshold on to a high value, and then subsequently change it again, there is some weird behaviour that results in the graph breaking.  You may notice the nodes collect in the top left.  Reviewing outputs in the console shows the following error message:

**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'weight' of undefined**

But I can't for the life of me work out why that's happening sometimes, but not every time.  I'm fairly new to D3, so any help & advice would be greatly appreciated, and I hope that I've provided all the required information for someone to give me some pointers.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you inspect your data when the error condition occurs, you are losing a `source` reference in a link to one of the nodes (it goes undefined):

```
[Object]
 0: Object
   source: undefined
   target: Object
   value: 75
   __proto__: Object
 length: 1
 __proto__: Array[0]
```

I'm not sure why, but I rewrote your threshold function to work on the `d3` link and nodes objects (instead of going back to source json) and it behaves as expected:

```
var masterNodes = graph.nodes;
var masterLinks = graph.links;
function threshold(thresh) {
    graph.nodes = [];
    masterNodes.forEach(function(d,i){
        if (d.value > thresh){
            graph.nodes.push(d);
        }
    });         
    graph.links = [];
    masterLinks.forEach(function(d,i){
        if (d.value > thresh){
            graph.links.push(d);
        }
    });    
    restart();
}
```

Updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e9L3aq4k/6/).